# Problems with passing Lambda LINQ statement as Func<>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I'm writing some examples to help me use Func<> and Lambda as I need to unravel the previous developers code on the project I am on and he uses techniques that I am not familiar with.

So I've written a few examples of increasing complexity from a Simple LINQ query to passing the LINQ as a FUNC to a method.  That all seems OK.

Then I switched from LINQ to Lambda.  Simple works OK but I can't figure out how to pass the Lambda as (in?) a Func<>.

My code is below.  I've marked the bit I'm stuck on as WHAT_GOES_HERE

```
private void some method()
{
   Dictionary<int,string> dic = new Dictionary<int,string>();

   //Set the data into the dictionary
   dic.Add(1, "Mathew");
   dic.Add(2, "Mark");
   dic.Add(3, "Luke");
   dic.Add(4, "John");
   dic.Add(5, "John");

   #region Simple LINQ as Lambda

   string searchName = "John";
   var match4 = dic.Where(entry => entry.Value == searchName).Select(entry => entry.Key);

   //Get the data out of the return from the query
   foreach (int result in match4)
   {
       int keyValue = result;
   }

   #endregion


   #region Passing the Simple LINQ as Lambda as a Func<>

   //uses the above Lambda - This works although the name used is the value of searchName
   IEnumerable<int> match5 = RunTheMethod(deligateName => match4, "John");

   //I want to have an inline Lambda as the first parameter
   IEnumerable<int> match6 = RunTheMethod(WHAT_GOES_HERE?, "John");

   foreach (int result in match6)
   {
      int keyValue = result;
   }

   #endregion
}


   public IEnumerable<int> RunTheMethod(Func<string, IEnumerable<int>> myMethodName, string name)
   {
      IEnumerable<int> i = myMethodName(name);
      return i;
   }
```

Any thoughts?
Richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* you want:

```
 RunTheMethod(name => dic.Where(entry => entry.Value == name)
                         .Select(entry => entry.Key),
              "John");
```

but it's not entirely clear...

Answer (score 1):

Annonymous delegate example:

```
 IEnumerable<int> match6 = RunTheMethod((name) => 
{ 
     //do something with name 
     return new List<int>(); 
}, "John");
```

Your `Func<string, IEnumerable<int>>` type means that it's expecting a delegate to a method that takes a string for the first parameter and will return a `IEnumerable<int>`

in the syntax `(name) => {}` name is the argument name and can be accessed inside of the braces {}.

Comment: You don't even need the parentheses around name.  You only need parentheses if there are multiple parameters.  Can just be `name => { /* code here */ }`.

Comment: Thanks @Jacob you are correct, but I do this as a practice. makes it very clear.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `match4` is not a lambda, it's just `IEnumerable<int>`. I guess you want something like

```
var selector = searchName => dic.Where(entry => entry.Value == searchName)
                                .Select(entry => entry.Key);
var ints = selector("John");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a lambda expression there that matches: `Func<string, IEnumerable<int>>`.  Takes a `String`, and returns an `IEnumerable<int>`.  It could be anything.  For example:

```
S => S.Chars("T").Select(C => C.Length)
```

...would be valid.  This would return an IEnumerable of the length of each string, if the given string was split into smaller strings delineated by the *T* character.

Not what you probably want to do, just an example.  My guess is that **you don't want to solve your problem this way**, but this is the type of thing that would need to be at the spot you indicate.  Any lambda expression where a `String` is turned into an `IEnumerable<T>`

Answer (score 1):

```
 Func<string, IEnumerable<int>> searchFunc = (searchValue) => dic.Where(entry => entry.Value == searchValue).Select(entry => entry.Key);

 IEnumerable<int> match6 = RunTheMethod(searchFunc, "John");
```

Hope this will answer your problem